# Question regarding proof of a limit which equals e ( the compound interest one).

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, logarithms, exponential-function

To prove the limit is e you do the following

$$ 
L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n
$$

\begin{align}
\ln L 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}  n \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)}{1/n},
\end{align}
which you can evaluate with L'hopital's rule (take derivative of top and bottom, since both
go towards 0):
\begin{align}
\ln L 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)}{1/n} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{n}}\left(\frac{-1}{n^2}\right)} {\frac{-1}{n^2}}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{n}}\\
&= 1.
\end{align}
Since the natural log of your limit is $1$, the limit itself must be $e$.$$$$

I cant understand the second statement in which we take the log of both sides and switch the limit and ln . The argument for doing such a thing is that the limit exists and the function is continuous (log is continuous) but how do we know the limit exists .

So don’t we need to prove

$$ 
L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n
$$
Exits before showing the above proof (and how do we prove it exists) or am i missing something

Comment: How do you define $e$? Some define it as this limit, so it is essential to include.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Define exp(x) as it being same as it’s derivative

Comment: Well you can prove the existence by using the continuity of $\exp$ function. Since $n\log(1+(1/n))\to 1$ in your approach we have $(1+(1/n))^n=\exp(n\log (1+(1/n)))\to\exp (1)$.

Comment: More generally when dealing with strictly monotone continuous functions you don't have to worry about existence of limit. Here log is continuous as well as strictly monotone on its entire domain. The same thing can not be done with square function. $a_n=(-1)^n$ has no limit but its square has limit $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is increasing and bounded above (by $4$). Therefore, it converges. The remaining problem is therefore to find its limit.

Comment: How did you know it is bounded by four?

Comment: Actually, it's even bounded above by $3$, since\begin{align}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&=1+\frac nn+\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!n^3}+\cdots\\&=1+1+\frac1{2!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)+\frac1{3!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\\&<1+1+\frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}+\cdots\\&=3.\end{align}

Comment: No, I most definitely did *not* use Taylor's theorem. All I used was the binomial formula. Yes, something must be justified.

Comment: I don't see how, but, anyway, the binomial formula is a much more elementary subject than Taylor's theorem.

Comment: If n is not a natural number then is the sequence still increasing or does that not matter if it does not matter why does it not matter? Because if n is not a natural number you can’t use Binomial theorem.

Comment: If $n$ can be any real number, then it doesn't make sense to talk about sequences here.

Comment: 0k so you simply used the theorem a bounded monotonic sequence converges is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: here we are assuming it to be a sequence(so only natural nos) but when using l'hopitals we are considering it to be a function am i correct or wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So for the l'hopital argumant like said in comments above you can just use l'hopitals rule on  nlog(1+(1/n))  as n goes to infinity and know it exists and goes to one and then exponentiate it since exp(x) is continous and get desired limit as e am i right or wrong ?

Comment: If you want to compute the limit using L'Hopital's Rule, then you must define $e^x$. And the answer depends upon how you define it.

Comment: I cannot answer that question, because I don't think that defining $e^x$ as a function which is equal to its own derivative makes sense. There ere infinitely many such function. Even if you add the condition that it maps $0$ into $1$ (in which case there is only one such function), then you must prove that there *is* a function which is equal to its own derivative (and which maps $0$ into $1$).

Comment: You can just start from defining log to be $\int_1^x 1/t \,dt$ then you can show that this integral is monotonically increasing  and as x -> ${\infty}$ it is unbounded and differentiable hence it must posses an differentiable inverse which you can denote as exp(x from here you can easily show that it must be its own derivative (and the only function to do so with exp(0)=1) and then easily show that exp(x)=$e^x$ for a number e st log(e)=1(this must exist because log is unbounded) (these all properties can be proven using properties of log(the integral) then  use l'hopitals to show above lim = e

Comment: Yes, if you define $\exp$ as the inverse of the logarithm and if you define the logarithm that way, then, yes, your approach is fine.

Comment: So if we define e your way we can go easily prove it is its own derivative and all...  and then using l'hopitals we can prove that the function (defined for all numbers) (not the sequence) also  converges to e as x-> infinity is that correct? use l'hopitals with the trick metioned in question comments.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Is there any way to prove that if the function converges for all n to e than the sequence of natural numbers will also converge to e or the sequence of two times every natural number it seems obvious but how rigorously

Comment: I suggest that you post this as a new question.

Comment: But do you know the proof is it a thm.

Comment: The proof of *what*? Please provide a complete and clear statement.

Comment: If a *function*  f(x) converges to a number a  as x->${\infty}$ will the sequence of values of the function for natural x also converge to the number or the sequence for 2times the natural x  etc... it seems obvious but I don’t know what theorem it is and how to prove it rigorously can you please tell me is it true , what theorem it is if it is not any theorem then how might one sketch such a proof?

Comment: Is it even provable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109680/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-vivaan-daga).